# For any fixed integer $ a \gt 1 $, how do you prove that $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ is not always prime given prime $ p \not \mid a-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers, repunit-numbers

I assumed this would be easy to prove but it turned out to be quite hard since the go to methods don't work on this problem.

Once we fix any $a\gt 1$, we need an algorithm to produce a prime $p$ that makes $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ composite and $a \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$. One method to prove compositeness is to consider it as a polynomial and find polynomial factors. However, $\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots +x+1$, being the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p}(x)$, is irreducible and this leads to a dead end. (The case when $a$ is a perfect power leads to a reducible polynomial resulting in an easy proof for that case, but this does not work for any other $a$).

Another method is to check if a prime $q$ can divide $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ for two different values of $p$. Suppose that $q \not = p$ divides$ \frac{a^{p}-1}{a-1}$, then $a^p \equiv 1 \pmod q$, implying that the order of $a$ mod $q$ is either $1$ or $p$. The order cannot be $1$ because if:
$$ \begin{align} a & \equiv 1 \pmod q \\ \implies \frac{a^p-1}{a-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} a^i & \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} 1^i \pmod q \\ & \equiv p \not \equiv 0 \pmod q \end{align} $$

Therefore, the order of $a$ has to be $p$ and $a^x \equiv 1 \pmod q$ has a solution if and only if $x$ is a multiple of $p$. Obviously, no other prime is a multiple of $p$ and therefore $q$ divides only one $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$.
When $q=p$, Fermat's little theorem, $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$, forces $a \equiv 1 \pmod p$ which is not allowed as per the question statement. Another dead end.

The funny thing is that once you check this for different values of $a$, it is easy to find a $p$ that satisfies the conditions and our required number seems to be composite for most $p$. For example, $p=11$ works for $a=2$ (Mersenne composite) and $p=5$ works for $a=3$. However, there doesn't seem to be a pattern that can be harnessed to extend this to all $a$. It is possible that I'm missing something obvious.

While researching online, I found out that these are precisely the repunit numbers with base $a$ and prime exponent, $R_p^{(a)}$. But I couldn't find a proof of my question anywhere.

**EDIT:** The same question can be asked for $\frac{a^p+1}{a+1}$ with the conditions now being $p$ an **odd** prime not dividing $a+1$. This is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{2p}(a)$ as opposed to $\Phi_{p}(a)$.

A weaker question would be to ask if for every $a>1$, there is a prime $p$ (satisfying the conditions) that gives a composite output to either $\Phi_{p}(a)$ or $\Phi_{2p}(a)$.

Following a proof idea [@Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/883143/derivative) mentioned in a comment below, if $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime, $q=2p+1$ divides $\Phi_{p}(a)$ iff $\left( \frac{a}{q} \right)=1$ and $a \not \equiv 1 \pmod q$. Similarly,  $q$ divides $\Phi_{2p}(a)$ iff $\left( \frac{a}{q} \right)=-1$ and $a \not \equiv -1 \pmod q$. Since $a \equiv 0, \pm 1$ for only finitely many primes and $\left (\frac{a}{q} \right) = \pm 1$, the (conjectured) existence of infinitely many Sophie Germain primes would prove our weaker result.

(This question actually came up naturally when I was trying to prove that for any fixed base $a$, there are infinitely many Fermat pseudoprimes to that base. I managed to prove that result using different methods, but I could not prove the result in the question).

Comment: Another easy case is when $a$ is even and $a+1$ is composite, we can see that $p=2$ works. But this still leaves out infinitely many even $a$.

Comment: You claim to have proven that for every (even) base $a$ , there are infinite many fermat-primes to that base, that is , infinite many primes of the form $a^{2^k}+1$ ? The opposite is expected, and this problem is widely open. Did I misunderstand the last part ?

Comment: As easy it seems at first glance, I think it is very difficult (if possible at all) to prove that for every positive integer $a$, $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ is composite for some prime $p$ not dividing $a-1$ , although intuitively, this "must" be the case.

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry, I mistyped that. I meant Fermat pseudoprimes. I have since edited that.

Comment: (+1) by the way, an interesting question

Comment: Thank you. I realised it wasn't easy when I worked through it, but I didn't really expect it to be open. I hope there is some deep/obscure result that has proven this result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163764/prove-that-every-number-ending-in-a-3-has-a-multiple-which-consists-only-of-on/163827#163827  , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4126555/n-relatively-prime-with-10-then-show-that-there-exists-another-natural-num 

Related.

Comment: Is there some reason  not to use little Fermat? $\bmod p$, the fraction $\equiv 1$, which means that it very often will not be prime.

Comment: @Keith Backman I'm not sure I understand the question. As I mentioned in the post, by Fermat's little theorem $a^p \equiv 1 \pmod p$ only if $ a \equiv 1 \pmod p$ which is forbidden by the question.

Comment: Little Fermat says $a^p \equiv a \bmod p$ or $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$. Thus, no matter what $a$ is or is not by assumption, $a^p-1 \equiv a-1 \bmod p$ and the fraction is identically $1 \bmod p$.

Comment: I don't see how that proves anything. We already know that there exists at least one prime $q$ (in fact infinitely many) that is $1 \bmod p$ for every prime $p$.

Comment: Wonder whether [Aurifeuillian factorizations](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/number_theory/aurifeuillian.pdf) come to the fore?

Comment: @jyrki I did happen to look at the Wikipedia page of [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization). According to that, such a factorization for this case exists if and only if $a=k^2 \cdot p$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. That takes care of a lot of $a$ but still leaves out an infinite amount.

Comment: Indeed, @arbashn. I even posted that as an answer. But then I remembered that $a$ rather than $p$ is fixed in this question :-)

Comment: If $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime and $q=2p+1$, by Euler's criterion $(a^p-1)/(a-1)\equiv 0 \mod q$ iff $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $q$ other than $1$. This way for each Sophie Germain prime you "halve" the available residue classes that $a$ can be.

Comment: @Derivative This is a fascinating method that hadn't crossed my mind. Even if you assume the infinitude of Sophie Germain primes, I don't think it can take care of all $a$. However, I think there is a way to use this to reduce the general case to only squarefree $a$. I can't seem to ensure that $a' = k^2 \cdot a$ always avoids the forbidden conditions. Someone else probably can.

Comment: @Derivative That is the best we have so far. Do consider posting it as an answer. It may well be that with this question a group effort, gradually taking us the distance (or failing to do that), is the best way.

Comment: @Derivative I wholeheartedly agree with Jyrki.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928022 . Since, as that question says, it appears to be open whether there are infinitely many composites of the form $2^p-1$, this question is probably very hard.

Comment: @David I assumed this question would be more tractable since it asks for only one composite number of the form. Is there an argument showing that existence of one composite leads to proof of infinitely many composites for general $a$?

Comment: I don't have a proof that one composite leads to infinitely many, but my intuition is that asking for just one doesn't make it easier.

Comment: @arbashn If anyone knew such a proof, the infinitude of Marsenne primes would be solved in an instant, as for example $2^{11}-1$ is not prime.

Comment: @David I defer to your expertise. I would still be satisfied in an answer expounding an argument that assumes reasonable conjectures (like the existence of infinitude of Sophie Germain primes for example).

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch I'm not sure if you're referring to the main question or my previous comment, but I don't see how either of those implies infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Comment: @arbashn I am sorry, it seems that the word "Marsenne-prime" burnt itself into my vocabulary. I meant the problem of the infinitude of Marsenne-composites (so to say), the question from the post David mentioned. You asked for a proof showing that the existence of one composite implies infinitely many composites. This would of course imply that there are infinitely many Marsenne-composites, as we have many examples of primes $p$ such that $2^p - 1$ is not prime. But I just reralized, I really made a mistake. As by assumption we would have one composite for any a, examples for a=2 dont suffice.

Comment: Anytime $a-1$ is prime then $a^p-1$ would have to be a semiprime.

Comment: @Roddy This is not true. Try $a=3, p=5$ or $a=4, p=5$.

Comment: $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}=q\in\mathbb{P}\implies a^p-1=(a-1)q$ which has exactly 2 prime factors any time $a-1$ is prime ...

Comment: @Roddy It is not true that $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1} \in \Bbb{P}$. I provided a counterexample, $\frac{4^5-1}{4-1} = \frac{1023}{3} = 11 \cdot 31$. I have also included many conditions for $a$ in my question and the comments where there always exist counterexamples.

Comment: My point was for the contradiction of the original fraction not always being prime, we can assume the negation ( that it is) . My result follows from the negation.

Comment: @Roddy Sure, then it just seems like the problem is rephrased. Is there a proof that $a^p-1$ is not always semiprime when $a-1$ is prime? This also applies only to the small set of $a$ where $a-1$ is prime.

Comment: That I don't know, but for $a\equiv r\pmod 6$ then $a^p-1\equiv a-1\pmod 6$ for odd $p$ and $r=\pm 1$

Comment: Doh* $r\equiv 0,2$